# How to concatenate a local variable with a string in Stata

Tags: python, stata

I have a very large DO file that I need to control for whether the code is run in Linux or Windows.

To do this, I thought I would add this chunk of code at the top of the file:

```
// Set OS variable for filesystem/directory control: values are: {linux, win}
local os = "linux"
```

And then whenever I had to select the correct filesystem's directory output I would have:

```
if "`os'" == "linux" {
    use "/mnt/DataResearch/DataStageData/CV_PATIENT_LABS.dta"
}
else {
    use "\\mrts-400-netapp\DataResearch\DataStageData\CV_PATIENT_LABS.dta"
}
```

The problem is that there are a LOT of `use`, `save` and `merge` statements in the code with hardcoded directories in them, so that putting this type of control into the DO file would not only be tedious, it would not be the most elegant of solutions.

In python, I would just define a variable `dir_out` as such:

```
if os == 'linux':
    dir_out = '/mnt/DataResearch/DataStageData/'
elif os == 'win':
    dir_out = '\\mrts-400-netapp\DataResearch\DataStageData\'
else:
    pass
```

and then throughout the DO file, just concatenate dir_test to the file name like:

```
use = dir_out + "CV_PATIENT_LABS.dta"
```

However, I have not for the life of me figured out how to do that in Stata-ease.

A colleague suggested using the built-in Python interpreter to do this, but I can't see how that would be any better than having a ton of the `if-then-else` control sequences interspersed throughout the code.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: You can use forward slashes to indicate WIndows filepaths in Stata; it will translate for you.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1567651-how-to-concatenate-a-local-variable-with-a-string-in-stata It's a good idea to tell people about cross-posting to save on wasted effort. It's explicitly requested on Statalist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A local macro in Stata  (not called a "local variable") can be concatenated with a string like this:

```
. local old "start here"

. local new "`old' and follow there"

. di "`new'"
start here and follow there
```

or like this:

```
. local new = "`old'" + " and follow there"

. di "`new'"
start here and follow there
```

See [here for an introduction to local macros](https://www.stata.com/manuals/u18.pdf).

Comment: How do I use thtis then in my `use`, `save` and `merge` statements? Can I just do: `use "`new'"`` (assuming "`new'" is the concatenation of the path and filename)?

Comment: Okay, yes it does work. Still not the most elegant, but I suppose, this is not python. Thanks1

Comment: Expecting non-python to behave like python is futile if non-python came first unless the inspiration for some syntax was the same.I don't see what is inelegant here. You can concatenate using juxtaposition or using `+` and the latter is what you seemed to be asking for.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit gratuitous of a comment aimed at the "different" coding idiom of Stata! I humbly take it back.

Answer (score 0):

Actually did not need the second local macro.

This worked

```
"`old'and follow there"
```

which allowed me to easily changes all instances of directories with the local macro name. A bit more elegant tthan having to define a second local macro.